# Find value $x$ of equation $e^x=\tan (e^x)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I want to find the values of $x$ for which

$$e^x=\tan(e^x)$$

How can I proceed?

I tried to plot the graph and it looks like it intersect $x$ axis at infinitely many points.

[image]
Can someone please direct me in the right direction.

Comment: It is easier to solve the equation $y= \tan(y)$ and then consider $y=e^x$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewrite the equation as $u=\tan u$ with $u=e^x$. Observe that $u=0$ is a trivial root, and all others are fairly close to $r_n=(\frac12+n)\pi$, with $n=\pm1,\pm2,\pm3$ ... and infinite number of roots.

Although there are no close-form solutions, clean, yet accurate, analytic approximations are known, such as the one below,

$$u_n = r_n - \frac1{r_n}$$

Listed below are the first few, along with the exact values in parentheses.

$$u_1 = \frac{3\pi}2-\frac2{3\pi}=4.500 \>(4.493)$$

$$u_2 =  \frac{5\pi}2-\frac2{5\pi}=7.725\> (7.727)$$

$$u_3 = \frac{7\pi}2-\frac2{7\pi}= 10.905\> (10.904)$$
$$…$$